# recursive FizzBuzz - why I can't reverse my array?

Tags: javascript, recursion, fizzbuzz

I am learning recursive functions. For fun, I tried the FizzBuzz coding challenge.

I am stuck as I don't understand why I can't reverse my array inside the recursive function.

Version 1

```js
  const fizzBuzzRecursive = num => {
    let results = [];
    if (num === 1) {
      return '1';
    } else {
      if (num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('FizzBuzz');
      } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('Buzz');
      } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
        results.push('Fizz');
      } else {
        results.push(''+ num);
      }
      newResults = results.reverse('')
      return newResults.concat(fizzBuzzRecursive(num - 1));
    }
   
  }
  
console.log(fizzBuzzRecursive(5));
// prints [ 'Buzz', '4', 'Fizz', '2', '1' ]
```

To make it work, I have to place the recursive function inside another function.

Version 2

```js
const fizzBuzz = num => {
  const fizzBuzzRecursive = num => {
    let results = [];
    if (num === 1) {
      return '1';
    } else {
      if (num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('FizzBuzz');
      } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('Buzz');
      } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
        results.push('Fizz');
      } else {
        results.push(''+ num);
      }
      return results.concat(fizzBuzzRecursive(num - 1));
    }
  }
  
  return fizzBuzzRecursive(num).reverse()
};

console.log(fizzBuzz(5));
// prints [ '1', '2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz' ]
```

Why does version 1 not properly and is there a way to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you are reversing an array with a single element, then concatenating it with the array returned by the next recursive call. In effect, this will not reverse anything, and the results will be concatenated together starting at the deepest level of recursion.

```js
const fizzBuzzRecursive = num => {
    let results = [];
    if (num === 1) {
      return ['1'];
    } else {
      if (num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('FizzBuzz');
      } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
        results.push('Buzz');
      } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
        results.push('Fizz');
      } else {
        results.push(''+ num);
      }
      return fizzBuzzRecursive(num - 1).concat(results);
    }
   
  }

console.log(fizzBuzzRecursive(5));
// prints [ '1', '2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz' ]
```

To achieve the reversal, simply swap the order of the concatenation, also making sure to return `['1']` inside of an array as your base case to make sure that it is able to concatenate with the other recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me an explanation :)

Comment: I have another question for you. I tried to convert the output of this function from an array to a string. 
I added join("") at the end of the return statement, but it didn't work. I am obviously missing something. Would you mind letting me know what's wrong with this? Thanks in advance. 
---
return fizzBuzzRecursive(num - 1).concat(results).join("");
---

Comment: The reason why `join("")` cannot be added to the recursive return is because `join()` is an `Array` method, not a `String` method. Adding `join()` to the recursive return changes the return type from an `Array` to a `String`, which means we would be calling `join()` on a `String` once we hit more than one level of recursion. To fix this, you can just call `join()` a single time after the function return, i.e. `fizzBuzzRecursive(5).join("")`. Alternatively, you can omit the `join()` function and make your `results` variable a string that you concatenate to with each recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below to reverse an array

Option 1

```
let arr = ['Buzz', '4', 'Fizz', '2', '1' ];
console.log(arr); // returns ['Buzz', '4', 'Fizz', '2', '1']
arr.reverse(); 
console.log(arr); // returns ['1', '2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz']
```

NB arr.reverse actually modifys the array.

Option 2

```
function recursive(array){
    let result = [];
  array.forEach((value, index) => {
    result.unshift(value);
  })
  return result;
}  
console.log(recursive(arr)); // returns ['1', '2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz']
```

Option 2 explanation
loops through the arr and unshift the value. The unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array.

- first time is adds ['Buzz'] to result array
- second time it adds ['4', Buzz] to result array
- third time is adds ['Fizz', '4', 'Buzz'] to result array
- fourth time is adds ['2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz'] to result array
- fifth time is adds ['1', '2', 'Fizz', '4', 'Buzz'] to result array

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: happy it helped, please up vote if you found my answer useful.